# Changing CPU frequency policies in OS X

Tags: macos, performance, cpu

I have Core i5 processor with nominal 2.3 Ghz speed. But, according to Intel Power Gadget, most of the time the frequency is much lower. Even during intensive usage. It's 0.8-1.6 Ghz.
I noticed that some operations work slower than they could.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to change default CPU frequency policy? You know, on Windows there are 3 modes, on Linux there are also several options (ondemand, performance, conservative, powersave etc.)

Comment: @Buscar웃 maybe he want to boil some water :p

Comment: @Buscar웃 : `i3/i5/i7 CPUs are not supported.` what do you mean by intensive usage ?

Comment: Could you show us your Activity monitor to see what is slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `top` in the Terminal. This will tell you where all your CPU and/or memory is going in more detail than activity monitor (`man top` to learn more about it). My immediate assumption is that your CPU isn't maxing out because it has no reason to. The default power management by both Apple and Intel does its job very well; I would guess you get this slow tab switching when you have lots of applications open, or a few very large ones.

If your Mac is taking time to compress and expand memory, it will run slower. If (heaven forbid) you have actually used more memory than you have physical RAM, your MacBook is dumping dynamic data to the hard drive. This will run SUPER slow, but use relatively few clock cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Running a home made multithread prime calculator on a Quad i7 2.0Ghz here's what I have :
[image: Intel Power Gadget picture]

As you can see, it goes beyond the nominal CPU speed and reach the Boost limit (2.6Ghz).
So I conclude that it depend of how the software is written and how it manage the CPU usage.

So Mac OS seems to automatically allow resources to need it. Maybe when you mean `intensive usage` it's not so intensive.

Comment: ...but you didn't answer the question about CPU performance policy.

Comment: @lid right ! I'll edit my answer to try to answer it ;)

Comment: At those operating conditions, and prolonged time, you will start getting junction leakage and electron migration effects, shortening the life if the IC. AFAIK, the self destruct prevention TC switch is at 110 Dgr. Celsius.

Comment: Well, maybe it is not intensive, but why does it work slow then? I mean, sometimes even tab switching or opening system preferences can be a pain (when CPU is actually free). It would be great if it worked on slightly higher frequencies by default.

Comment: @troorl maybe your looking to the wrong device which slow your computer down

Comment: @Thomas Any thoughts on what it could be? My MacBook is from 2011, it has 8 Gb RAM. Windows works better on this hardware. Not much better, but considerably.

Comment: @troorl look in your Activity Monitor to see who is at the top of the CPU list.

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's the point: sometimes system acts slow even when nobody uses CPU more than 1% or so.

Comment: @troorl HDD ? SSD ? what's the reading speed ? (use blackmagic disk speed test)

Comment: @troorl then we need to look in to the Console and see what is holding it back :)

Comment: @Thomas I have slow HDD (5200 RPM). Do you think SSD would help? It doesn't seem that I/O is a bottle neck.

Comment: @troorl we don't know where is the bottle neck, the only thing I know is that your processor shouldn't be the issue. Do you want to run my program to see if the CPU goes up ?